# How to delete a ContentDocumentLink

Tags: apex, delete, contentdocumentlink, contentworkspace

I wan't to create a `ContentDocumentLink` and delete him in an other function, i tried this code:

```
// function of creation:
ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink(
    ContentDocumentId = doc.Id,
    LinkedEntityId = ws.Id
);
insert cdl;

// function of deletation
delete cdl;
```

But when I run this function of creation and after function of deletation, I have this error:

```
Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 06A0E000002ea8HUAQ; first error: DEPENDENCY_EXISTS, Cannot complete this operation.
// this part is translate by me:
You can't delete this document of is own library
```

I found this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274499/unable-to-delete-contentdocumentlink), but I didn't understood how he made to delete the `ContentDocumentLink`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just delete `ContentDocumentLink`.

There issue that you are facing and what was described in the related question is following:

If you upload document from the code and create first ContentDocumentLink it has `ShareType` of `I` and it is primary, which means you can't delete it (you need to delete file instead).

If you have something like 10 ContentDocumentLink, you can easily delete 10 of them (9 of them if 1 of 10 is primary).

Please ask follow up question if something is unclear.
Also refer to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm)

Comment: Can I change the primary `ContentDocumentLink` when I create a new link whit a `shareType` set to `I` ? or any other way?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change sharing for the user who uploaded the file?

Comment: No when I create my link **a** to a library, he is set with `I` by default (I tried to change it but got an other error), then I create a new one **b** to an other library and I wan't to **a**. My question was can I set the link **b** as primary and then delete **a**?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `Primary` as there is no field on `ContentDocumentLink` called `Primary`

Comment: There is no such field. From what I remember it's "primary" because it has "I" in share type or something similar. I definitely remember that you can't delete original CDL, but I'm not sure right now how it's determined in the System

Answer (score 0):

For the ContentVersion you can't remove it but you can remove ContentDocument, ContentDocumentLink, ContentDistribution.
Example:

```
   List<ContentDocument> contentDocuments = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument  
   WHERE Id IN :contentDocumentIds];
   List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinksToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM 
    ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :contentDocumentIds];
   List<ContentDistribution> contentDistributionsToDelete = [SELECT Id FROM 
    ContentDistribution WHERE ContentVersionId IN :contentVersionIds];
    try {            
        if (!contentDocuments.isEmpty()) {
            delete contentDocuments;
        }
        
        if (!contentDocumentLinksToDelete.isEmpty()) {
            Database.delete(contentDocumentLinksToDelete, false);
        }
        
        if (!contentDistributionsToDelete.isEmpty()) {
            Database.delete(contentDistributionsToDelete, false);
        }
    } catch (DmlException e) {
        System.debug('An error occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
```